# Proof by induction, system of equations

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations

We conjecture that there is a formula of the form
$\sum_{j=1}^{n}{j^2} = an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d$ for all integers n ≥ 1     (3)

(a) Assuming that such a formula is true, find the value of a, b, c, d.
(Hint: Substituting the first few values of n yields a system of
linear equations in a, b, c, d, which has a unique solution).

So for this I have that

1 = a + b + c + d

4 = 8a + 4b + 2c + d

9 = 27a + 9b + 3c + d

16 = 64a + 16b + 4c + d

Which after I reduced it in a matrix yields a=0, b=1 c=0 d=0; Have I done this part correctly?

(b) With the constants a, b, c, d you found in part (a), use mathematical
induction to prove (3).

So now I have ∑j=1 to n such that j^2 = n^2

Base case:

for n = 1
LHS = 1  =  RHS = 1

Assume true for n=k
∑j=1 to k such that j^2 = k^2

Prove true for n= k+1
∑j=1 to k+1 such that j^2 = ∑j=1 to k such that j^2 + (k+1)^2

= k^2 + (k+1)^2

I have no idea where to go from here though.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{j^2}=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$?

Comment: In part a, the left hand sides of the linear equations should be $\sum_{j=1}^n j^2$, not simply $n^2$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. So should I have 1 = a + b + c + d; 4 = 9a + 5b + 3c + 2d; 9 = 36a + 14b + 6c + 3d; 16 = 100a + 30b + 10c + 4d?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of $\sum$?  The phrase "such that" is somewhat alarming; it is not that each term is equal to the right hand side, but rather that the entire sum is.  Does this provide any information you did not know before?

Comment: Oh ok, I think I was misinterpreting the definition of the summation, I never knew it meant that.

Comment: Assume for n.  Then sum j^2 to n+1 = sum j^2 to n plus (n+1)^2 $= an^3 + bn^2+cn+d+(n+1)^2$.  So you just need to prove that equals $ a (n+1)^2 +b (n+1)^2+c (n+1)+d $ for the a b c d values you chose.

Comment: You did not do the linear equations right.  You set them to the squares.  You need to set them to the *sum* of the squares.  1,5,15,and 31. Not 1,4,9,and 16.

Comment: @fleablood how did you get the sum of the squares as 1,5,15 and 31? When I re-attempted the question I got they were 1, 5, 14 and 30?

Comment: Lyla, I think you are correct with your sums and fleablood has made a mistake (adding 10 instead of 9 to get from 5 to 15).

Comment: I made an error.  Adding in my head I added 9 + 1 + 4 as 9 + 1 + 5.  and from there 16+15 = 31 instead of 16+14 = 30.

Comment: @alphacapture actually my mistake was to add 9 to the sums (5 and 1) rather than to the squares (4 and 1).  Once made...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what *did* you think summation meant?

Comment: @fleablood I thought it meant that you just compute each individual value. Like if I had to evaluate the summation from n=1 to n=k I didn't take into account that I need to add the values from 1 to k, I thought I just needed to find a value for k. If my confusion makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

"(Hint: Substituting the first few values of n yields a system of linear equations in a, b, c, d, which has a unique solution)."

So

$\sum_{j=0}^0 j^2 = 0 = a*0^3 + b*0^2 + c*0 + d = d$

$\sum_{j=0}^1 j^2 = 1 = a*1^3 + b*1^2 + c*1 + d = a + b + c +d$

$\sum_{j=0}^2 j^2 = 1 + 4 = 5 = a*2^3 + b*2^2 + c*2 + d = 8a + 4 b + 2c + d$

$\sum_{j=0}^3 j^2 = 1 + 4 + 9= 14 = 27a + 9b + 3c + d$

So $d = 0$.  $a = 1/3, b = 1/2, c = 1/6$.

===

Prove by induction:

In solving the linear equations we've shown it is true for $n = 0,1,2,3$

Assume it is true for $n = k$.  Then:

$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} j^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k j^2 + (k + 1)^2=$

$k^3*1/3 + k^2*1/2 + k*1/6 + (k^2 + 2k + 1)=$

$k^3* 1/3 + k^2(3/2) + k(7/6) + 1$.

Now

$(k+1)^3*1/3 + (k+1)^2*1/2 + (k+1)*1/6 = $

$(k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k+ 1)*1/3 + (k^2 + 2k + 1)*1/2 + k/6 + 1/6 = $

$k^3*1/3 + k^2 + k + 1/3 + k^2/2 + k + 1/2 + k/6 + 1/6 = $

$k^3 *1/3 + k^2(3/2) + k(7/6) + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/6 = $

$k^3 *1/3 + k^2(3/2) + k(7/6) +1 = $

So $\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} j^2 =(k+1)^3*1/3 + (k+1)^2*1/2 + (k+1)*1/6 $

So by induction, we have shown $\sum_{j=0}^n j^2 = 1/3*n^3 + 1/2*n^2 + 1/6*n$.